# Implementing a mutable IndentityDictionary in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

Trying out some older code and I've come across an IdentityDictionary. From what I know NSDictionary uses equality, not identity to compare Objects. Judging by it's use it seems I would need a mutable IdentityDictionary anyway?

I've read two threads on this and it seems to be quite difficult to do, Class clusters, hash functions and so on.

[Does NSDictionary's objectForKey: rely on identity or equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403561/does-nsdictionarys-objectforkey-rely-on-identity-or-equality)

[Implementing -hash / -isEqual: / -isEqualTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112373/implementing-hash-isequal-isequalto-for-objective-c-collections)

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: Which class are the keys?

Comment: Do you need to write a custom class? [`NSMapTable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmaptable?language=objc) already supports what you need.